# echo $variable in another echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm stacked.

Can't get it, how put this variable:

```
$cat_logo = get_field('game_logo', $tax . '_' . $term_id);
```

This var contain link, that should be In this code:

```
<?php echo wpthumb( '$cat_logo', 'width=100&height=100&crop=0' ) ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `$cat_logo` is a string, it will be pushed out as a string.

This will work:

`<?php echo wpthumb( $cat_logo, 'width=100&height=100&crop=0' ) ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You miss the difference between **variable name** and **variable content**. There's no point quoting variable name at all:

```
<?php echo wpthumb($cat_logo, 'width=100&height=100&crop=0' ) ?>
```

If you need for any odd reason, you must use double quotes:

```
<?php echo wpthumb("{$cat_logo}", 'width=100&height=100&crop=0' ) ?>
```

Docs: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

Dont close your variable into " " or ' ' as it will read the variablename as a string, let it write out itself as a string. Try this:

```
<?php echo wpthumb( $cat_logo, 'width=100&height=100&crop=0' ) ?>
```